# Equivalent condition about the norm of a linear isomorphism

Tags: operator-theory, linear-transformations, banach-spaces

Let $X, Y$ be Banach spaces(finite dimensional, if necessary).
$T:X\rightarrow Y$ is a linear isomorphism.
Is it true that $\Vert T\Vert\Vert T^{-1}\Vert<1+\epsilon$ implies $|\Vert Tx\Vert-\Vert x\Vert|<\epsilon \forall x\in X$? I cannot get any relation between them. Thanks for help.

Answer (score 1):

It is false. Just take $X=Y=\Bbb R^2$ and $T(x,y)=(y,x)$. Then $\|T\|=\|T^{-1}\|=1$ and
$$\|T(1,0)-(1,0)\|=\|(1,-1)\|=\sqrt 2$$

If the base field is $\Bbb C$ you can even take $X=Y=\Bbb C$ and $T(z)=iz$.

Answer (score 1):

If you take a non-zero dilation operator $T : X \mapsto X : x \mapsto \lambda x$, then $\|T\| \|T^{-1}\| = 1 < 1 + \varepsilon$ for all $\varepsilon > 0$, but $|\|T x\| - \|x\||$ is unbounded when varying $\lambda \neq 0$.